# Stopping a Running Spark Application (Databricks Interactive Cluster)

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm using **databricks** with an interactive cluster.  If I review their management user-interface, there is only one "application" listed.  And when I try to kill it, I always get this message

> HTTP ERROR 405
> Problem accessing /app/kill/. Reason:
>
> ```
>    Method Not Allowed
> ```

The end result is that I'm forced to restart the entire cluster.  I use their "cluster pool" feature which makes the wait time a bit less. but it still involves waiting for about a minute before I'm able to get back to work.

The reason I need to restart the application is to swap fresh jar's into the spark environment.  Otherwise when I repeatedly use addJar(), I run into some annoying jar-hell issues (class not found errors and such).

Why does Databricks only list one application at a time in their "interactive" cluster?
Why doesn't databricks have a way to stop one application and start another in its place (without restarting the whole cluster)?

This affects development productivity when we are forced to sit around waiting an extra minute for no good reason.  It is already pretty hard to be productive with spark.